# Laravel 5.3 Seeding

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have an error when I try to seeding data to tables in database. I have 2 tables : **author** and **books**. The table has relation using ORM. But, when I try to execute it using

> php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

I got this error :

> a four digit could not be found
>   data missing.

And here is my code

My model "author" :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function books(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
}
}
```

Model "books" :

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name','author_id','amount'];

public function author(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');

}
}
```

my code for seeder :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Author;
use App\Book;

class BooksSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $author1 = Author::create(['Muhammad Ariel Purnama']);
    $author2 = Author::create(['Titania Eka Yuliandini']);
    $author3 = Author::create(['Shikaku kookokokoko']);

    $book1 = Book::create(['title' => 'goood boy', 'amount' => 3, 'author_id' => $author1->id]);
    $book2 = Book::create(['title' => 'life observer', 'amount' => 4,'author_id' => $author2->id]);
    $book3 = Book::create(['title' => 'Blekok Borokokko', 'amount' => 2, 'author_id' => $author3->id]);

}
}
```

and my DatabaseSeeder code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call(UsersSeeder::class);
    $this->call(BooksSeeder::class);
}
}
```

thank you for your attention.

Comment: I can't definitively say this is the problem, but when you're creating authors, you're missing the key in the array. `$author1 = Author::create(['name' => 'Muhammad Ariel Purnama']); // etc.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use should use correct field names, and put the correct key:

```
$author1 = Author::create(['name'=>'Muhammad Ariel Purnama']); //use name key
$author2 = Author::create(['name'=>'Titania Eka Yuliandini']); //use name key
$author3 = Author::create(['name'=>'Shikaku kookokokoko']); //use name key

$book1 = Book::create(['name' => 'goood boy', 'amount' => 3, 'author_id' => $author1->id]); //replace title for name
$book2 = Book::create(['name' => 'life observer', 'amount' => 4,'author_id' => $author2->id]); //replace title for name
$book3 = Book::create(['name' => 'Blekok Borokokko', 'amount' => 2, 'author_id' => $author3->id]); //replace title for name
```

Double check if your the column of Books table is `title` or `name`, and then do the adjustments in your model and seed.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm new in laravel.